# Illegal unit of measure(pt inserted) while drawing edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw arrows at particular grid points for sequence of diagrams using tikx, but I get "Illegal units of measure (pt inserted)" when trying to use the following command:

```
\newcommand*{\drawhigharrow}[2]{
    \ifdim #1 < #2 {
        \draw (#1*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize) edge[thick,out=90,in=180] (#2*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize);
        \draw (#2*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=0,in=90,->] (#2*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize+0.1);
    } \else {
        \draw (#1*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=90,in=0] (#1*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize);
        \draw (#1*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=180,in=90,->]
              (#2*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize+0.1);        
    }
    \fi
}
```

Sorry for asking, but I can't figure out what may be going wrong - the calculations seem to be all very standard (just multiplication and addition). Can someone help me spot my mistake?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: You can't just perform calculations on lengths or numbers the way you do. What is `\gridsize` defined as? You would need an expandable calculation macro to achieve this; add `\usepackage{xfp}` to your preamble and try with `\fpeval{#1*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize}` ...

Comment: @Werner This is TikZ (judging by the tag and `\draw`), and doing e.g. `2*3.4` or `4pt+2cm*0.5` is not a problem in TikZ coordinates.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Nice.

Comment: I will note though that it would have been nice if you provided a complete example, i.e. something like my code below, which not only showed the macro, but also how you use it, which saves potential answerers from making assumptions. And, having a complete example makes it just a little bit easier to test the code.

Comment: Cool, thanks, will do next time - sorry for not having provided the full example.

Answer (score 4):

`\ifdim` is for comparing dimensions/lengths. Presumably you use the command like `\drawhigharrow{1}{2}`, i.e. with just numbers. If you add `pt` after `#1` and `#2` in the `\ifdim` statement, it seems to work.

Alternatively you could use `\ifnum #1 < #2`, in which case the comparison is for numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\gridsize{1cm}
\newcommand*{\drawhigharrow}[2]{
    \ifdim #1pt < #2pt { % note the addition of pt
        \draw (#1*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize) edge[thick,out=90,in=180] (#2*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize);
        \draw (#2*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=0,in=90,->] (#2*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize+0.1);
    } \else {
        \draw (#1*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=90,in=0] (#1*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize);
        \draw (#1*\gridsize, 6*\gridsize) edge[thick, out=180,in=90,->]
              (#2*\gridsize+0.5*\gridsize, 5*\gridsize+0.1);        
    }
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawhigharrow{1}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```